# How to render mathematical on PDF documents

Tags: pdf, latex, text-rendering

I am trying to render mathematical expressions to a PDF document using a low-level library such as libharu or pdflib; I am having problem rendering several special signs, such as radical signs.

A solution I can think of is to use draw line methods to render the radical sign. This is straightforward. But this doesn't work for `integrate` or other signs such as `"\left("`. I consulted KaTeX source code and I found it uses a built in svg graphics, which is not applicable when rendering a PDF document

(Maybe I was not making it clear: the svg presented in KaTeX was actually a glyph pre-rendered, while my application scenario is to render PDF directly with couple of given parameters, such as position and height, etc. ).

Are there anyone who know the PDF rendering mechanism of LaTeX or similarly stuffs that can help me out? thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you think SVG is not applicable to PDF? There are many applications that support drawing SVG into PDF documents.

Comment: (Maybe I was not making it clear: the svg presented in KaTeX was actually a glyph pre-rendered, while my application scenario is to render PDF directly with couple of given parameters, such as position and height, etc. ).